# OpenMP for loop ignores num_threads clause

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, openmp

I have the following code in VS2008:

```
int i,j;
bool pr = false;
#pragma omp parallel for private(pr) num_threads(2)
for(i=0;i<PIC_X;i++)
{
    int rank = omp_get_thread_num();
    int count = omp_get_num_threads();
    if ( !pr )
    {
        printf_s("Hello from thread %d of %d\n", rank, count);
        pr = true;
    }
    for(j=0;j<PIC_Y;j++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(Not trying to make a nested OpenMP loop, in case you're wondering). The problem is, the num_threads clause has no effect whatsoever: I only ever get "Hello from thread 0 of 1" on the output. I tried using `omp_set_num_threads(2)` as well, to no avail. What gives?

Comment: Check out http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/32-openmp-traps-for-c-developers/ - It really helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set pr outside of the parallel region and then made pr private by putting it in a private clause.  That means that each thread has a pr, but the private pr variables are not initialized.  Use firstprivate rather than private for pr, so that the private variables are initialized.

However, you are incorrect about loop counters being private by default.  The loop counter for the worksharing (or canonical) for (i.e., the variable i) is private (section 2.4.1 for Construct of the OMP V2.0 spec).  But "j" is not.  See the OpenMP V2.0 spec (which is what Microsoft supports in VS2008), section 2.7.2 Data-Sharing Attribute Clauses:

> If a variable is visible when a parallel or work-sharing construct is encountered, and
>   the variable is not specified in a sharing attribute clause or threadprivate
>   directive, then the variable is shared. Static variables declared within the dynamic
>   extent of a parallel region are shared. Heap allocated memory (for example, using
>   malloc() in C or C++ or the new operator in C++) is shared. (The pointer to this
>   memory, however, can be either private or shared.) Variables with automatic storage
>   duration declared within the dynamic extent of a parallel region are private.

As for omp_get_num_threads() returning a 1, all I can think of is that you didn't compile this wih the OpenMP flag enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If OpenMP splits the outer loop in 2 (i.e. one process gets 0..PIC_X/2) and the other gets the last half, only one process will see i==0.

And if your image is organized like all images I have seen, the outer loop should be Y and the inner loop should be X, and the inner loop should be OpenMP'ed, because that's how images are generally organized in memory.

Comment: +1 even though OP edited the post to remove the `if ( i == 0 )` code xcramps was originally correct.

Comment: While that was kind of embarrassing, it wasn't the problem: question has been edited with a (hopefully) correct solution to only print once per loop, and I still only get "Hello from thread 0". Furthermore, `get_num_threads()` also constantly yields 1.

Comment: It isn't possible that you're running on a unicore machine, huh? Also, you need to make i and j private too.

Comment: Oh, and setting pr means only one thread will print the Hello.

Comment: Running on a dual core machine, and even then, wouldn't specifying `num_threads` force OpenMP to start that many threads, even if it's more than the number of cores? Also, setting `pr` as private should guarantee that each thread gets its own value to set (this wouldn't explain why `get_num_threads()` returns 1 anyway). Loop counters are private by default.